# How to generate dynamic table from time range (POWER BI)

Tags: powerbi, dynamic-tables

POWER BI
We have a table (A) with id_document, from_date, to_date, amount, We need to generate a dynamic table (B) which has many records for each record in table (A). The number of records in the table (B) will be defined by (to_date - from_date).

The new table (B) should have this fields id_document, date, [amount / (to_date - from_date)]

```html
<h1>Table A</h1>
<table>
<tr><td>Doc_id</td><td>From_date</td><td>To_date</td><td>Amount</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>01/08/2019</td><td>05/08/2019</td><td>10000</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<h1>Table b</h1>
<table>
<tr><td>Doc_id</td><td>date</td><td>Amount</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>01/08/2019</td><td>2000</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>02/08/2019</td><td>2000</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>03/08/2019</td><td>2000</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>04/08/2019</td><td>2000</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>05/08/2019</td><td>2000</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Posting sample data and expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following example might help. Enter the code when creating a new table from the modeling tab in Power BI. This will create a table where every contract is combined with a table with single days. It adds a column which evaluates whether the row should be included or not.

```
Expanded = 
    var _calendarTable = CALENDAR( MIN ( Contracts[From] ) ; MAX ( Contracts[To] ) )

RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CROSSJOIN ( Contracts ; _calendarTable ) ;
        "Inclus" ; IF ( AND ( [Date] >= [From] ; [Date] < [To] ) ; 1 ; 0 )
    )
```

The next step could be to choose either a filter or a second calculation to get to the end result. You could opt for creating another new table using CALCULATETABLE().

```
Final = 
    CALCULATETABLE (
        Expanded ;
        Expanded[Inclus] = 1
    )
```

I know of no way yet to do both in a single step, while as far as I know, unlike DAX studio e.g., Power BI needs to evaluate the first table first in order to have subsequent DAX access values from it.

I hope it helps you in the right direction at least.

Answer (score 0):

Tables in PowerBi are populated upon refresh and unfortunately, cannot be dynamic. You can create dynamic Tables in a measure and use them as a reference but they will not exist after execution.